# Create a Google Site Page using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

Here  is my code

```
function test2(){
var titlePage="test titre";
var namePage="test-titre";
//Creer nouvelle page dans le site (avec le nom) avec modele gestion de projet
var Site=SitesApp.getSite('site','gestionorgairsoft');
  var PageMod=SitesApp.getPageByUrl('https://sites.google.com/site/gestionorgairsoft/projets/op-full-72').getHtmlContent();
var PageParent=SitesApp.getPageByUrl('https://sites.google.com/site/gestionorgairsoft/projets');

  var parent=Site.getChildByName('projets');
 var newPage= parent.createWebPage(titlePage, namePage, PageMod);
  newPage.setParent(SitesApp.getSiteByUrl('https://sites.google.com/site/gestionorgairsoft/projets'));
}
```

Got an "Internal Error" on line  var newPage= parent.createWebPage(titlePage, namePage, PageMod);

but I really don't know how to do

Context is :
- Site : https://sites.google.com/site/gestionorgairsoft
- Parent : 'https://sites.google.com/site/gestionorgairsoft/projets

Need to create a new page, titled "titlePage" as child as a copy of page https://sites.google.com/site/gestionorgairsoft/projets/op-full-72

Answer (score 0):

I tried code like this, and it worked for me on one of my Sites. I'll substitute your Site and Page names in the code:

```
function createCopyOfPage() {
  var titlePage = 'test titre';
  var namePage = 'test-titre';
  try {
    var site = SitesApp.getSite('site', 'gestionorgairsoft');
    var parentPage = site.getChildByName('projets');
    var origPage = parentPage.getChildByName('op-full-72');

    var pageContent = origPage.getHtmlContent();

    var newPage = site.createWebPage(titlePage, namePage, pageContent);
    newPage.setParent(parentPage);
  } catch (err) {
    Logger.log(err.toString());
  }
}
```

The try/catch should help log some more detailed error messages if you encounter any errors when trying to run this. If it does catch any errors, please update with what was logged, since that might help narrow down what's causing any problems for you.

Comment: looked promising but  
`Exception: Erreur liée à un service : SitesApp: Internal Error`

Comment: Could you post your script's project key? You can find it from File > Project Properties in the script editor.

Comment: Mk3f8yxqtyEy7AaXUzKI5kWbsYizgyvoY

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the parent Page is not a direct child of site homepage.

I have used the following method with success in that case.

```
   //Get page
   var matches = site.search('projets'); 
   for(var i in matches) {
   Logger.log(matches[i].getName());  // logger can help you find if this is correct. 
   }
   var page2 = matches[0]
```

It is very far from ideal as it requires a unique name so there is only an index[0].

Otherwise though you need a child of a child o a....